# Is it possible to access the partial list content while being Sow'ed or must one wait for it to be Reap'ed?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been learning Sow/Reap. They are cool constructs.  But I need help to see if I can use them to do what I will explain below.

What I'd like to do is:  Plot the solution of `NDSolve` as it runs. I was thinking I can use `Sow[]` to collect the solution (x,y[x]) as `NDSolve` runs using `EvaluationMonitor`. But I do not want to wait to the end, `Reap` it and then plot the solution, but wanted to do it as it is running.

I'll show the basic setup example

```
max = 30;
sol1 = y /. 
   First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
     y, {x, 0, max}];
Plot[sol1[x], {x, 0, max}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}]
```

[image]

Using Reap/Sow, one can collect the data points, and plot the solution at the end like this

```
sol = Reap[
    First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
      y, {x, 0, max}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]]][[2, 1]];

ListPlot[sol, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}]
```

[image]

Ok, so far so good. But what I want is to access the partially being build list, as it accumulates by `Sow` and plot the solution. The only setup I know how do this is to have Dynamic `ListPlot` that refreshes when its data changes. But I do not know how to use Sow to move the partially build solution to this data so that `ListPlot` update.

I'll show how I do it without Sow, but you see, I am using `AppenedTo[]` in the following:

```
ClearAll[x, y, lst];
max = 30;
lst = {{0, 0}};
Dynamic[ListPlot[lst, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, max}, All}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}]]

NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, max}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {AppendTo[lst, {x, y[x]}]; Pause[0.01]}]
```

[image]

I was thinking of a way to access the partially build list by Sow and just use that to refresh the plot, on the assumption that might be more efficient than `AppendTo[]`

I can't just do this:

```
ClearAll[x, y, lst];
max = 30;
lst = {{0, 0}};
Dynamic[ListPlot[lst, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All]]

NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, max}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {lst = Reap[Sow[{x, y[x]}] ][[2, 1]]; Pause[0.01]}]
```

Since it now Sow one point, and Reap it, so I am just plotting one point at a time. The same as if I just did:

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, max}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {lst = Sow[{x, y[x]}]; Pause[0.01]}]
```

**my question is, how to use Sow/Reap in the above, to avoid me having manage the lst by the use of AppendTo in this case. (or by pre-allocation using Table, but then I would not know the size to allocate) Since I assume that may be Sow/Reap would be more efficient?**

ps. What would be nice, if `Reap` had an option to tell it to `Reap` what has been accumulated  by `Sow`, but do not remove it from what has been Sow'ed so far. Like a passive `Reap` sort of. Well, just a thought.

thanks

**Update: 8:30 am**

Thanks for the answers and comments. I just wanted to say, that the main goal of asking this was just to see if there is a way to *access* part of the data while being Sowed. I need to look more at `Bag`, I have not used that before.

Btw, The example shown above, was just to give a context to where such a need might appear. If I wanted to simulate the solution in this specific case, I do not even have to do it as I did, I could obtain the solution data first, then, afterwords,  animate it.

Hence no need to even worry about allocation of a buffer myself, or use `AppenedTo`. But there could many other cases where it will be easier to access the data as it is being accumulated by Sow. This example is just what I had at the moment.

To do this specific example more directly, one can simply used `Animate[]`, afterwords, like this:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
max = 30;
sol = Reap[
    First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
      y, {x, 0, max}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]]][[2, 1]];

Animate[ListPlot[sol[[1 ;; idx]], Joined -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, max}, All}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}], {idx, 1, 
  Length[sol], 1}]
```

Or, even make a home grown animate, like this

```
Remove["Global`*"];
max = 30;
sol = Reap[
    First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
      y, {x, 0, max}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]]][[2, 1]];
idx = 1;
Dynamic[idx];
Dynamic[ListPlot[sol[[1 ;; idx]], Joined -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, max}, All}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}]]

Do[++idx; Pause[0.01], {i, 1, Length[sol] - 1}]
```

**Small follow up question:**  Can one depend on using ``` Internal``Bag ``` now? Since it is in `Internal` context, will there be a chance it might be removed/changed/etc... in the future, breaking some code? I seems to remember reading somewhere that this is not likely, but I do not feel comfortable using something in `Internal` Context. If it is Ok for us to use it, why is it in Internal context then?

(so many things to lean in Mathematica, so little time)

Thanks,

Comment: Do you think using tags for `Sow` combined with the second and third arguments for `Reap` may work?

Comment: @kguler, good idea, never though of it. I just started learning Sow/Reap, but will look into your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I think you follow-up question is worth a post of its own.  I probably won't have time to respond, not that I have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experimentation shows that both `` Internal`Bag `` and linked lists are slower than using `AppendTo`.  After considering this I recalled what Sasha told me, which is that list (array) creation is what takes time.

*Therefore, neither method above, nor a `Sow`/`Reap` in which the result is collected as a list at each step is going to be more efficient (in fact, less) than `AppendTo`.*

I believe that only array pre-allocation can be faster among the native *Mathematica* constructs.

Old answer below for reference:

---

I believe this is the place for `` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag ``, and `` Internal`BagPart ``.

I had to resort to a clumsy double variable method because the `Bag` does not seem to update inside `Dynamic` the way I expected.

```
ClearAll[x, y, lst];
max = 30;
bag = Internal`Bag[];
lst = {{}};

Dynamic@ListPlot[lst, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All]

NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, max}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Internal`StuffBag[bag, {x, y[x]}];
                       lst = Internal`BagPart[bag, All];
                       Pause[0.01]}
]
```

Comment: What trouble are you having with the `Bag` version? It seems to work just like Nasser's method with `AppendTo` in version 8.0.4

Comment: +1. ``Internal`Bag`` is also what I'd use here. AFAIK, Reap` and `Sow` are internally implemented using ``Internal`Bag``, by the way.

Comment: @Leonid, isn't `AppendTo` the better choice here?  `BagPart[bag, All]` is slower than `AppendTo[lst, x]` in my tests, so why use it at all?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard May be you are right, I did not test. I expected bags to be faster, but this is a special case since at every step, the entire accumulated list is queried. As an alternative, one can probably construct a custom plotting function which would only need the last point to update the plot - I think this should be possible.

Comment: @Leonid I like that idea.  I suggest you implement it if you have time (I don't).